# How do I prove that $\min_\Phi x'x-x'\Phi(\Phi'\Phi)^{-1}\Phi'x$ equivalent to $\max_\Phi tr(x'\Phi(\Phi'\Phi)^{-1}\Phi'x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

How do I prove that $\min_\Phi x'x-x'\Phi(\Phi'\Phi)^{-1}\Phi'x$ equivalent to $\max_\Phi tr(x'\Phi(\Phi'\Phi)^{-1}\Phi'x)$ where $x$ is an $N\times T$ matrix and $\Phi$ is an $N\times r$ matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are minimizing a function of the form $a - f(\Phi)$. Your statement follows from the fact that 
$$
\min_{\Phi} a - f(\Phi) = a + \min_{\Phi} (-f(\Phi)) = a - \max_{\Phi}f(\Phi).
$$